# Self intersection of a line $L$ in a surface $X\subset\Bbb{P}^3$ of degree $d$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, projective-space, intersection-theory

> Let $X\subset\Bbb{P}_\Bbb{C}^3$ be a smooth algebraic surface of degree $d$ and $L\subset X$ a line in it. Compute the selfintersection $L^2$.

I'm only able to deal with it when $d=1$, in which case $X\simeq \Bbb{P}^2$ and $L$ is a line in $\Bbb{P}^2$, which has self intersection $1$.

For the other cases I'm stuck, even for $d=2$. I know I need to somehow "move" $L$ through $X$ in order to get some $L'$ with $L\sim L'$ and see what happens with $L\cap L'$.

I've tried to look at the example of the one-sheeted hyperboloid $X=V(x^2-y^2+z^2-w^2)$. I know this is a ruled surface, so I imagined that a line $L\subset X$ could be moved into a disjoint line $L'$, so that $L\cap L'=\emptyset$ and $L^2=0$.

But first, I don't know how to formalize this, meaning: how do I find $f\in k(X)$ so that $L-L'=\text{div}(f)$? And second: the one-sheeted hyperboloid seems like a very specific example; how can I find a general solution?

Comment: Mohan's answer handles the question in the title, but regarding quadrics: all smooth quadric surfaces in $\mathbb P^3$ are projectively equivalent, so your hyperboloid is sufficient. To formalize, I would advise you to avoid trying to do the intersection in coordinates. The standard path is 1) prove that $X \cong \mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$, 2) compute the Picard group of the latter surface using the excision sequence, and 3) observing that two lines intersect if they lie in different rulings, but are disjoint (being fibers of a projection map) if they lie in the same ruling (your case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way is to use genus formula. For a curve $C\subset X$, $X$ a smooth projective surface, $2g(C)-2=C\cdot(C+K_X)$. So, in your case $-2=L\cdot(L+K_X)$. But, by adjunction,  $K_X=O_X(d-4)$ and thus $L\cdot K_X=d-4$. So, we get, $L^2=2-d$.

Comment: By $\mathcal{O}_X(d-4)$ you mean $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb{P}^3}(d-4)\big|_X$, right? How did you conclude that $L\cdot K_X=d-4$? (sorry if these questions are dumb, I'm still digesting all this sheaves/divisors/intersection stuff)

Comment: @rmdmc89 That is what Mohan means, yes. Since $K_X = \mathcal O_X(d-4)$, you can compute intersection numbers with $K_X$ by intersecting with a degree $(d-4)$ hypersurface in $\mathbb P^3$. One way to define degree of a hypersurface is by its intersection with a line, so $L.K_X = \deg(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(d-4)) = d-4$.

Comment: @rmdmc89 $L$ is a line, so intersection with $O_X(n)$ is just $n$.

Comment: @TabesBridges, according to what you're saying, the degree of the hypersurface $X\subset\Bbb{P}^3$ is $d-4$. That sounds very weird in comparison to what I'm used to, namely that the degree of $X=V(F)\subset\Bbb{P}^3$ is the degree of the homogeneous polynomial $F$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @rmdmc89 How do you get that from what I wrote? I said that the intersection of $L$ with the canonical class on $X$ is $d-4$, not the intersection of $L$ with $X$.

Comment: @TabesBridges, yes, I'm clearly confused. You wrote "you can compute intersection numbers with $K_X$ by intersecting with a degree $(d−4)$ hypersurface in $\Bbb{P}^3$". But which degree $(d-4)$ hypersurface are you refering to, and what will we intersect it with? You also mentioned the degree of a hypersurface being defined by the intersection with a line, then you write "$L\cdot K_X=...$", but where is the hypersurface here? (since $K_X$ is not a hypersurface, I figured it must be $X$)

Comment: Mohan, I'm not being able to formalize why $L$ intersected with $\mathcal{O}_X(d-4)$ is $d-4$. I tried to rewrite $\mathcal{O}_X(d-4)$ as $(d-4)\Pi\big|_X$, where $\Pi\subset\Bbb{P}^3$ is a hyperplane, but that didn't really help

Comment: @rmdmc89 The canonical divisor class $K_X$ is the restriction of the class of $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(d-4)$. In other words, the curve cut out on $X$ by any hypersurface of degree $(d-4)$ is a canonical divisor. The point is that restricting a hypersurface to $X$ (thereby obtaining a curve) and then intersecting with a line is the same thing as intersecting the hypersurface with the line in the ambient $\mathbb P^3$ (since the only points of intersection lie on $X$). Symbolically I guess you could write this as $L.D = L.(D|_X)$, where $D$ is the hypersurface...

Comment: ...but maybe it would make even more sense (albeit be clunkier to write) if I wrote this as $L.D = (L|_X).(D|_X)$ just to really emphasize that the LHS is the intersection of a curve and a surface in a threefold, while the RHS is the intersection of two curves on a surface.

As for your question to Mohan, one way to define the degree of a hypersurface is as the number of intersection points with a generic line. A line meets the hyperplane $\Pi$ in $1$ point, so it meets $(d-4)\Pi$ in $d-4$ points.